# AngularJS serverside variable to ng-init and methods sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I´v got a "detail" view and a controller that initilizes data with an id.

My view:

```
<div ng-app="AFApp" ng-controller="AgentCtrl" ng-init="init('@Model.Id')">
```

My controller:

```
$scope.id;
$scope.agent = {};

$scope.init = function (id) {
    $scope.id = id;
    getAgent();
    getAgentStatus();
    getSystemInfo();
    getActions();
};
```

The problem is that the method "getAgentStatus();" gets executed before "getAgent();". The "getAgentStatus" needs the $scope.agent data that "getAgent" provides. The function getAgentStatus has an attached timer, and it gets the value as the timer elepses but not in the init function. Can someone please help me out with the method execution sequence in angular controllers and how the id parameter is provided the best possible way.

See methods below:

```
function getAgent() {
        agentDataFactory.getAgent($scope.id)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.agent = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log('Unable to load data: ' + error.message);
            });
    };

function getAgentStatus() {

        if (typeof ($scope.agent.ServiceUrl) == 'undefined' || $scope.agent.ServiceUrl == null) {
           console.log('getAgentStatus: ServiceUrl is undefined ' + JSON.stringify($scope.agent));
        }

        agentDataFactory.getAgentStatus($scope.agent.ServiceUrl)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.agent.CurrentStatus = data.Status;
                $scope.agent.CurrentInterval = data.Interval;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log('Unable to load data: ' + error);
            });

        $timeout(getAgentStatus, 3000);
    };
```

Comment: Why can't you call `getAgentStatus()` inside the `success` handler for `getAgent()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that works as well. As I mentioned below. I am still curious of the reason for the method sequence behavior in the controller.

Comment: I am not sure if this related to asp.net, but by the looks of it, `getAgent()` is an asynchronous call that resolves a promise. Since it is asynchronous, it does get executed before `getAgentStatus()`, but after making the asynchronous call, getAgenStatus() is called immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `getAgentStatus()` as a callback parameter to `getAgent()` and have it executed in the `success` callback (at which point `agent` will be defined):

```
function getAgent(callback) {
    agentDataFactory.getAgent($scope.id)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.agent = data;
            callback && callback();
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            console.log('Unable to load data: ' + error.message);
        });
};

$scope.init = function (id) {
    $scope.id = id;
    getAgent(getAgentStatus);
    getSystemInfo();
    getActions();
};
```

---

#### Short explanation:

Some highlights first:

- `agentDataFactory.getAgent($scope.id).success(...).error(...);`:
  Creates a promise (which will be resolved) asynchronously and registers two callbacks, one if the promise is successfully resolved and one for the case of an error.
- `.success(function (data) { $scope.agent = data; })`:
  Registers a callbackfor when the promise is successfully resolved. **When** (and if) that happens, `$scope.agent` will be set.
- `function getAgentStatus() { if (typeof ($scope.agent.ServiceUrl...`:
  Tries to access some properties of `$scope.agent` and thus requires the object to be defined.

So, what happens with your code:

1. `getAgent()` is gets called.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
2. A promise is created that **when** resolved will set `$scope.agent`.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
3. `getAgent()` returns and `getAgentStatus()` is called.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
4. `getAgentStatus()` tries to access `$scope.agent`'s properties and fails.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
5. The promise created in step 2 is resolved and its `success` callback get executed.
   *[$scope.agent is finally defined]*

My version of the code ensures that `getAgentStatus()` is **not** executed before the promise is resolved and thus $scope.agent is defined:

1. `getAgent()` is gets called.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
2. A promise is created that **when** resolved will set `$scope.agent`.
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
3. `getAgent()` returns and other functions get called (e.g. `getSystemInfo()`, `getActions()`, etc.).
   *[$scope.agent is undefined]*
4. The promise created in step 2 is resolved and its `success` callback get executed.
   *[$scope.agent is finally defined]*
5. Only now does `getAgentStatus()` get called and it works as expected since...
   *[$scope.agent is defined]*

Take a look at the **[`$q` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q)** for more info on Angular promises.

Comment: Thanks very much, that actually did the trick in this particular situation. I will use that solution. I am however curious of the reaso for the method sequence behavior in the controller. Thanks again!

Comment: @Claes-PhilipStaiger: I added some explanation of what is going on in each case. Please, do let me know if it doesn't make sense :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it make sense. I will look in to the promise of the repository. I can call the getAgentStatus() when the promise is resolved. Is it recommended to add promises to the controller functions as well?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by your last question. In any case, promises are a good thing that make asynchronous stuff easier to handle and interact with. So, promises won't hurt anyone - at the very worst they might be unnecessary. (BTW, if this answer helped you with your problem, please consider accepting/upvoting it.)

Comment: I mean, I use promises to the functions in the datareposity where the async calls is made to the server. The repository methods is called from controller. My question was, is it nessesary to use promises in the controller methods as well and not only rely on "success". But maybe this question is a bit otiose. Further, I don´t see where I accept my question or your answers.

Comment: If you are fetching data (which is by definition an async operation) you can't avoid using promises. If your question is whether you should have your "promising" methods in the controller, the truth is that Angular Services are a better fit for such "utility" methods. You can accept an answer by checking the little checkmark on the left next to the answer. There are also two arrow-buttons (up for upvoting, down for downvoting).

Comment: Great input! About voting and accept answer. I have only an "uparrow" and a "flag" for spam. It might be because I´m fairly new to posting messages in this forum. However, I´ll use the "uparrow" since your comments are very useful!

Comment: The ones you refer to are just for comments. Look on the left of the first lines of my answer (not comments). Take a look **[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** for more info.

Comment: @Claes-PhilipStaiger: My answer is still unaccepted. unvoted and pretty sad :(

Comment: Sorry about that, this is done now. Thanks for all your input!

Comment: @Claes-PhilipStaiger: Hey, look how it is smiling and happy now :)